# Is there a library specially designed for storing Web Parts?

Tags: web-part, library

Is there a library designed to house web parts? I want to store reusable web parts in a library. I know there is a "`Web Parts Gallery`" at the root site level, but I do not have access nor will I get access in the future.

Thanks

Comment: Inorder to use Webpart you need to place in the web part gallery. You can also check `edit page -> insert webpart -> upload webpart` and see where it goes.

Comment: Yes, I know. I want to store reusable web parts in a repository/library and was asking if that's possible in any other capacity other than using the "Web Part Gallery". I know how to add web parts to a page.

Comment: You can create a Document Library and use it. But for adding it into page, you need to download a copy and then upload it.

Comment: Seems like the easiest thing to do is to just store the web parts locally on my PC. I created a doc library, uploaded a web part file, downloaded it locally to my PC, tried to Import the web part to a page, didn't work. Received a message "List doesn't exist".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web part gallery is a special document library that is located at the root of each site collection. I dont think you can create another custom Web Part Gallery, because this library having direct links with web.config files safe control section.

Web Parts are server-side controls that run inside the context of site pages in Microsoft SharePoint Foundation, when you upload a web part in Document Library it will treat that web part as a file, then that webpart not become part of safecontrol section.

As a workaround, I suggest, ask your admin...create a folder in that gallery and give you permission on that folder.